A function whose points of discontinuity form an arbitrarygiven $F_\sigma$ set.
From 'Counterexamples in Analysis' by Bernard R. GelbaumJohn ,M. H. Olmsted i studied this:
The part underlined in red is unclear to me.
If $c\in (A_n\setminus A_{n-1})\setminus I(A_n\setminus A_{n-1})$ ($I$ denote interior of a set) then $c\in\partial (A_n\setminus A_{n-1})$.
Then every neighbourhood of $c$ has points in $A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$ and in $\mathbb{R}\setminus(A_n\setminus A_{n-1})$.
Then?

Essentially we need to show that $\mathbb{R}\setminus B_n$ has $c$ as a limit point, since $f$ differs from $f(c)=2^{-n}$ by at least $2^{-n-1}$ on this set.
Suppose that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $c$ that has empty intersection with the complement of $B_n$. Then $U\subseteq B_n$. So $c$ is an interior point of $B_n$. But I think it is clear that $B_n$ has no interior points, since any interior point of $B_n$ would also be an interior point of $A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$, but then it would be an element of $A_n\setminus A_{n-1} \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Oh thanks, i didn't have thinks that $I(B_n)=\emptyset$.

No problem! If this answer was satisfactory, you may accept it, so it is clear to others that this question has been answered.
